# What should I do to avoid error message "Object variable or With Block Variable not set"

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am new in VBA script and have created small script to get the data from website however I always get error message "Object variable or With Block Variable not set" . please help me to get the best script to display the price "Rp 16.425"

Below are the sample of both HTML and my script :

HTML as screen below :

```
<div class="S4G9wXKj">
<h3 data-testid="hSRPProdName" class="Ka_fasQS">Buku MATEMATIKA BILINGUAL Kelas X SMA/MA - Yrama Widya</h3>
<div itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<span itemprop="price" class="_3fNeVBgQ">
<span data-testid="hSRPProdPrice">Rp 16.425</span>
</span>
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="IDR">
<div class="ifULVzgL"><div class="_3z5GLerJ">
<span class="UY2SWg6T" data-testid="spnSRPProdTabShopLoc">Yogyakarta</span>
<span class="_1GDgKs4K">Yrama Widya Books</span></div></div>
<div class="_3dCNp1CF"></div></div></div>
```

and this is my script :

```
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim BHTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.tokopedia.com/search?st=product&q=buku&ob=3&pmin=16411&origin_filter=sort_price", False
XMLPage.send
BHTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 3

    Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("[data-testid=hsRPProdPrice] span").Item(i).innerText

Next
```

[image]

Comment: At what line does this error appear?

Comment: You should start VBA code with `Option Explicit`, so the declaration of variables will be enforced.

Comment: I was posting an answer but not sure it's enough.  `HtmlDoc` isn't ever loaded with data, use `BHtmlDoc` which is the object you load the HTML into.  In addition, your selector is wrong

Comment: at this line " Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("[class=S4G9wXKj] div").Item(i).innerText"

Comment: sorry martin ..i mean this line

Comment: Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("[data-testid=hsRPProdPrice] span").Item(i).innerText

Comment: if I change  with "Length" instead of "item" ini this line "Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("[data-testid=hsRPProdPrice] span").Item(i).innerText " then the data displayed is 0 ( zero )